# The difference between 'weak limit point' and 'converge weakly'

Tags: weak-convergence, weak-topology, weakly-cauchy-sequences

For the following theorem.

*Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $H$ and let $x:[0,+ \infty) \rightarrow H$. Assume that*

$\quad$ (i) *for every $z\in S$, $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left\|x(t)-z\right\|$ exists;*

$\quad$ (ii) *every **weak sequential limit point** of $x(t)$, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, belongs to $S$.*

*Then $x(t)$ **converges weakly** as $k\rightarrow \infty$ to a point in $S$.*

My questions are:

- What is the difference between 'weak limit point' and 'converge weakly'?
- What is the difference between 'weak limit point' and 'weak sequential limit point'?

The first one is the main question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A weak sequential limit point is a point $h$ such that $x(t_n) \to h$ weakly **for some sequence** $t_n \to \infty$. $x(t)$ converges weakly to $h$ if $x(t) \to h$ weakly as $t \to \infty$ which means $F(x(t)) \to F(h) $ as $t  \to \infty$ for every continuous linear map $F$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While I have another question, the weak sequential limit point of $x(t)$ may not be unique, right?

Comment: Right, it may not be unique. @RenHaixin

Comment: I have completely understood. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: After thinking about it for a while, I still have a question. Does $x(t_n) \to h$ weakly means $F(x(t_n)) \to F(h)$ as $t_n \to \infty$ for every continuous linear map $F$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Great, I really understand now, thank you for your patience to answer my questions!